# Script launches on USB insertion but launches twice

Tags: bash, ubuntu, usb

As a project, I'm trying to write a small bash script to do two things upon inserting a USB drive:

1) Copy files from a specific directory on the USB to a specific directory on the computer (Mac Mini running Ubuntu)

2) Launch a separate program (that will then use the files transferred from the USB)

However, the script is running twice, which is undesirable since I only want the separate program to launch once.

The rule I added to launch the script is:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", RUN+="/path/to/script"
```

I realize this launches on any USB insertion, but part of the idea is to be robust enough to work for any USB drive. The Mac Mini will be dedicated to this program only and only have USB drives with the proper directory structure inserted.

Comment: I'd probably try to look at in logs to see what events are actually happening.  It's likely that the process of inserting a drive may result in more than one type of event which qualifies under your broad rule.  Perhaps you should build some sort of exclusion mechanism, such as a couple of seconds delay-on-trigger, and before that a check for any other instance in delay-on-trigger state and termination if one is found.

Comment: I figured it out. What I needed to do was change the rule to 

    ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device",ACTION=="add",SUBSYSTEM=="usb",RUN+="/usr/local/bin/USBInsertScript"

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342226/udev-rule-execute-2-times